# OpenCV exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, camera, pycharm, opencv, imshow

This is my program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the result:

`exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

I am running my program in Windows 7. My Python version is 3.6 in Pycharm.

Comment: Is that the entire output? Is there an error message as well? What happens when you run your code - do any windows appear?

Comment: Did this answer your question, or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I got this code to run on my computer by changing the 1 to a 0 in the line `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`. This integer value determines which camera is used to capture an image. Passing 0 tells OpenCV to use the first camera on your device. If your device, like mine, only has one camera, then telling it to use the second camera by passing 1 will result in errors.